# No puedo hacer funcionar el menú hamburguesa, ni posicionarlo a la izquierda, el menu desplegable no se ve

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://apoteotico.github.io/Portfolio/
El menú hamburguesa solo aparece cuando la resolución es menor a @media (min-width: 768px)

Solo descubrí que si borro este bloque, el menu hamburguesa se va a la izquierda:

```
   .logo {
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    nav ul {
        position: static;
        width: auto;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    nav li {
        border: none;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
}
```

Por lo demás no tengo idea hace rato vengo probando y lo subi al github.
(esta parte de abajo es editada con mis comentarios para dar mas detalles sobre el progreso)

*debo tener algo más que me interfiere con el posicionamiento del botón. sigo buscando. acá dejo mi repositorio por si quieren probar el código: github.com/Apoteotico/Portfolio. estoy bastante enroscado, igual no tengo apuro, sigo analizándolo. –

*ya pude acomodarlo a la izquierda, ahora solo me queda hacer funcionar el boton con el menu desplegable. subí el cambio del botón en la rama master de mi repo. gracias AugustoM me ayudó mucho tu respuesta a encontrar el error del botón! –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo en tu reglas de CSS, es que estas usando flex, y la propiedad "flex-direction: column", segun el tamaño del dispositivo tienes que cambiar esa propiedad a "flex-direction: row" cuando estes bajo 768px, en ese mismo breakpoint, puedes cambiar las reglas a los elementos del logo y la hamburguesa para que se muestren segun los necesites, si no quieres cambiarlos de lugar puedes usar la propiedad order para cambiar el orden en que se muestran y utilizar space between para justificarlos en los extremos.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-size: 18px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


nav {
  display: none;
}

button {
  order: 1;
}

.logo {
  order: 2;
}


@media (min-width: 768px) {
  header {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .logo {
    justify-content: flext-end;
  }
  
  button {
    display: none;
  }
  
  nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
  }

}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="logo">
            <h1 class="logo">&lt;/&gt;Apoteótico</h1>
            <!-- El logo -->
        </div>

        <button class="hamburger">☰</button>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Proyectos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Habilidades</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```